# What is the difference between scaling property when scaling factor is $-1$ and the time reversal property of Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

I came across this question when one of my students asked me about it.
Suppose that $L$ denotes the Laplace transform and that $L\{F(t)\}=f(s)$. By scaling property, we have $L\{F(-t)\}=-f(-s)$. The time reversal property of Laplace transform says that $L\{F(-t)\}=f(-s)$ and $L^{-1}\{f(-s)\}=F(t)$. But by the scaling property $L^{-1}\{f(-s)\}=-F(-t)$. When we say time reversal then we assume the time domain as $(-\infty,\infty)$ and we find that $L\{F(-t)\}=f(-s)$.
There is confusion with the scaling property and time reversal property. The question is, how to justify the difference between scaling and time reversal property and what is the physical significance of it?

Comment: The scaling property, $f(at)$ to $\frac{1}{a}F(\frac{s}{a})$ assumes that $a>0$ otherwise the transform does not converge in $\Re[s] >0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In scaling property, if we put $a=-1$, then what will be the practical difficulty?

Comment: if $a=-1$ then the Laplace transform kernel will grow exponentially for causal signal $t>0$ in$\Re [s] >0$.